# Windows Phone Style Item according to the Item Condition - XAML Style

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a RadDataBoundListBox (its an advanced listbox with more options and properties etc...) My ListBox is binded to a List of Notifications, every notification has a bool property Unread, what I want to do is if the Item is Unread (Unread = true) I want the font color to blue, and if Unread = false the font color stays white... I don't know how to do this

This my listbox code:

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="3,4,0,0" 
        Name="radListNotifications" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="453" 
        SelectionChanged="radListNotifications_SelectionChanged">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                                 
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Message}" 
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            Padding="0,3,0,0" 
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
                            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
                            LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" 
                            LineHeight="43" />

                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Time}" 
                            Opacity="0.65" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" 
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" 
                            Margin="0,0,0,13"/>
            </StackPanel>                              
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

And here is the code where I apply the ItemSource:

```
List<TimeTierUserActions.Notification> listNotifications = e.Result.ToList();
radListNotifications.ItemsSource = listNotifications;
```

Do you know how I can achieve this?
I mean if the notification is Read the font color stays the same, but if unread change the color of the item (notification).

Here is a screenshot of the ListBox when loaded

[click here to show my listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dHH4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a property on your object that denoted whether the message is unread or not, you should use a converter to determine the foreground colour...

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="{Binding Message}" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Padding="0,3,0,0" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" 
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
    Foreground="{Binding IsUnread, Converter={StaticResource UnreadBrushConverter}}" 
    LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" 
    LineHeight="43" />
```

Your converter will then take the unread flag as a parameter, like so...

```
public class UnreadMessageBrushconverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // hard-coded colours example,  you may want to look at 
        // using predefined resources for this, though.
        return (bool)value ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You'll also need to declare an instance of the converter in your XAML (in this case using the namespace "conv")

```
<conv:UnreadMessageBrushconverter x:Key="UnreadBrushConverter" />
```

If you're not familiar with converters, have a look here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: <conv:UnreadMessageBrushconverter x:Key="UnreadBrushConverter" />

When I insert this instance of the converter its giving me an Assembly Reference error, I think I need to add its reference, can you tell me what is the reference needed for this conv instance?

Comment: You need to add the namespace reference into the xaml page declaration.  Please see the link provided for a walk-through of using Converters.

Comment: ok I am checking it out :) thanks I assume this is the namespace:
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConverterParameterEx" 
    Width="400" Height="300">

Comment: In that example, yes it is.  I tend to use conv for the name, but only so I don't confuse myself about what is in the namespace and what isn't. ;)

Comment: I can't find a way to get the namespace working :S

    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeTierWP7Client"  

this is my namespace
but when I start writing <local:___ I cant find the UnreadMessageBrushconverter there
Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: 1 - check the namespace in the converter file - if, like me, you put it in a folder, your namespace may be something like TimeTierWP7Client.Converters.  2) Make sure you build the project successfully before you try to add the reference into the XAML.  If that doesn't work, check all your spellings.